# Artinian affine $K$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field and $A$ an affine $K$-algebra. Show that $A$ has (Krull) dimension zero (is artinian) if and only if it is finite dimensional over $K$.

Comment: If your $k$ - algebra $A$ is finite dimensional as a vector space over $k$ then it has to be Artinian. This is just linear algebra that the dimension $d$ of a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is such that $0 \leq d \leq \dim V$.

Comment: Related to [Zero-dimensional ideals and finite-dimensional algebras](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368448/zero-dimensional-ideals-and-finite-dimensional-algebras).

Answer (score 5):

Finite dimensional (as a vector space) algebras are zero dimensional: Using quotients, it is enough to prove that every finite dimensional domain is a field. But this is standard: The multiplication map by a nonzero element is injective, hence also surjective.

If $A$ is a zero dimensional finitely generated $k$-algebra, then it is artinian, and we may even assume that $A$ is local, say with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Now try to prove that each $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is finite-dimensional. Since $\mathfrak{m}$ is nilpotent, this shows that $A$ is finite dimensional (as a $k$-vector space).

Comment: The second part of your hint is unclear to me: $\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is finite-dimensional as an $k$-vector space or as an $A/\mathfrak m$-vector space? And is not the main point in the proof of the question that $A/\mathfrak m$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space?

Comment: Over $k$. But also over $A/m$, doesn't matter. Yes, $A/m$ is finite-dimensional over $k$, I assume such basic facts ...